# Making a stipulative definition

Tags: word-usage

In a philosophical text (not related to jurisprudence) I would like to explicitly make a stipulative definition. I can't quite make it sound good.

Some attempts

1. I stipulatively define X to mean ...
2. Stipulatively, I define X to mean ...
3. Stipulatively, X is defined to mean ...

All of them sound awkward to me. How should I write this?

Comment: Why don't you stipulate what you want?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe:

> Let us stipulate that X means ...

or, if you are elsewhere using the first person singular,

> I stipulate that X means ...

Note: I suppose a "stipulative definition" is  concept known in philosophy?  And you have to include the word "stipulate"?  In mathematics, I would just say things like

> Let X mean...
>     Let X be...
>     Let X = ...

and, more flexibly,

> ... is called X if ...
>   ... is said to be X if ...

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

> ... X, stipulatively defined as Y, ...

or

> ... X, stipulated to mean Y, ...

or

> ... X, stipulated as Y, ...

Answer (score 2):

[Stipulative definitions](https://www.thoughtco.com/stipulative-definition-1692143) are a type of definition but are not always identified by using the word *stipulate*.  There are a whole host of signals commonly used.

All of these are [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stipulative_definition) of stipulative definitions:

- Suppose we say that to love someone is to be willing to die for that person.
- Take "human" to mean any member of the species Homo sapiens.
- For the purposes of argument, we will define a "student" to be "a person under 18 enrolled in a local school".
- `Let X = any integer`

Indeed the examples in OP ― which aren't wrong ― probably sound awkward only because you're used to reading so many alternative ways of calling out a stipulative definition.